# How to get a clean IQueryable?

Tags: entity-framework, appfabric-cache

I have a problem with a Entity Framework and appFabric caching.
I need to generate a key of the query statement but in the Where clause i get the parameter value is equal than @p_*linq*_0.
How do I replace to the true value?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because AppFabric Caching stores data in a serialized way, it's not recommanded to store statefull data. You have to put only materialized items in the cache. In case, you do not follow this rule, you will have severe problems when querying your database with your context.

Anyway, the best way to use AppFabric Caching with EF is as a Second-Level a Cache.

Julie Lerman posted a few month ago a great article on MSDN.Check it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh394143.aspx).